# Proving the triangle inequality of a specalized vector norm involving matrices

Tags: matrices, vectors, normed-spaces

I am given that symmetric matrix $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $Q\succ 0$ (positive definite).  I am then tasked with proving that $\parallel x\parallel_Q$ is a vector norm (called the Q-norm). Of course vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  The norm function is defined according to the equation $\parallel \,x\!\parallel_Q = \sqrt{x^TQx}$.

I have already proven non-negativity, homogeneity and zero-vector properties. So:

- $\parallel x\parallel_Q > 0$, $\forall x\ne \vec{0}$.
- $\parallel x\parallel_Q = 0$, for $x=\vec{0}$.
- $\parallel \alpha x\parallel_Q = |\alpha| \cdot\parallel x\parallel_Q$

But Ive been struggling for days to prove sub-additivity, $\parallel x+y\parallel_Q \le \parallel x\parallel_Q + \parallel y\parallel_Q$.

I dont see a point in showing my work because it clearly wasnt fruitful. Id be wasting both our times repeating nonsense, wouldnt I?  It also wouldnt make sense for me to mislead you down one of my misconceived paths. Clean slate.

It makes sense to begin by squaring:
 $$\parallel x+y\parallel_Q^2 \le \parallel x\parallel_Q^2 + \parallel y\parallel_Q^2 + 2\parallel x\parallel_Q \cdot \parallel y\parallel_Q$$

$$(x^T+y^T)Q(x+y) \le x^TQx + y^TQy + 2\sqrt{x^TQx \cdot y^TQy}$$

But regardless which side I work on I hit a wall.

Ive tried thinking in terms of Rayleigh coefficients and comparing to eigenvalues. Ive tried considering $U^TDU=Q$ decompositions. Brute forcing the vector algebra. Ive distributed the left hand side into $x^TQx + y^TQy + 2x^TQy $, which allows me to simplify the expression into $x^TQy \le \sqrt{x^TQx \cdot y^TQy}$, which I dont know what to do with.  I get nowhere with all of my attempts.  Any help or guidance, pointers, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily construct a symmetric matrix $L$ with $L^2=Q$, eg. by using the Jordan canonical form $Q=U^TDU$ and then setting $L=U^TD^{1/2}U$, where $D^{1/2}$ is the diagonal matrix that has the squares of the values of $D$ on its diagonal.

Know consider
$$ \|x+y\|_Q^2 = x^TQx + y^TQy + 2x^TQy = \|x\|_Q^2 + \|y\|_Q^2 + 2x^TQy, $$
since $Q$ is symmetric. Know we write
$$2x^TQy = 2x^TLLy =2x^TL^TLy=2(Lx)^TLy, $$
since $L$ is symmetric. Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$ 2x^TQy = 2(Lx)^TLy \leq 2\sqrt{(Lx)^TLx}\sqrt{(Ly)^TLy} = 2\sqrt{x^TQx}\sqrt{y^TQy} = 2\|x\|_Q\|y\|_Q.$$
Together with the first equation you get
$$ \|x+y\|_Q^2 \leq \|x\|_Q^2 + \|y\|_Q^2 + 2 \|x\|_Q\|y\|_Q = (\|x\|_Q+\|y\|_Q)^2 $$
from which – by taking the root on both sides – the triangle inequality follows.

Comment: Forgive my linear algebra ignorance, but I have yet to prove the C-S Theorem holds for the Q-norm. Is it always true regardless of the norm?  Your approach to this problem is similar to what I tried, but you took it a step further. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I believe you have a type-o in your proof and it might effect the result. Im also not entirely sure how youre applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality here since I see matrices and vectors as opposed to the proper form of the norm Im trying to prove. I feel like youve employed the two-norm on your third line as opposed to the Q-norm.

Comment: Okay! :P Never mind. I totally get it now. Took me over an hour. Far more insightful for me than I originally thought.  It never even occurred to me to make use of other norms.